# Using Java Selenium(3.12), which firefox docker image should i use

Tags: selenium, docker, firefox

which firefox docker image shall i use

I saw on docker hub but there are most images for selenium firefox

As i am not running explicitly any selenium server.

I am using customized selenium jar.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

- **selenium/base**: Base image which includes Java runtime and Selenium Server JAR file
- **selenium/hub**: Image for running a Grid Hub
- **selenium/node-base**: Base image for Grid Nodes which includes a virtual desktop environment
- **selenium/node-chrome**: Grid Node with Chrome installed, needs to be connected to a Grid Hub
- **selenium/node-firefox**: Grid Node with Firefox installed, needs to be connected to a Grid Hub
- **selenium/node-chrome-debug**: Grid Node with Chrome installed and runs a VNC server, needs to be connected to a Grid Hub
- **selenium/node-firefox-debug**: Grid Node with Firefox installed and runs a VNC server, needs to be connected to a Grid Hub
- **selenium/standalone-chrome**: Selenium Standalone with Chrome installed
- **selenium/standalone-firefox**: Selenium Standalone with Firefox installed
- **selenium/standalone-chrome-debug**: Selenium Standalone with Chrome installed and runs a VNC server
- **selenium/standalone-firefox-debug**: Selenium Standalone with Firefox installed and runs a VNC server

Comment: I want to have standalone firefox

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: I am using selenium webdriver. 
Using gecko driver in my framework.
But on docker container i am not able to open firefox although using ./firefox -version command it shows the version firefox.
Display is also set.
I am not sure why it is not getting opened.